# Configurar ncurses en Codeblocks usando Ubuntu

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Estoy tratando de correr este programa en CodeBlocks teniendo como sistema operativo Ubuntu. El compilador es GNU GCC Compiler

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "ingrese letra" << endl;
    char letra;
    letra = getch();
    cout << "Su letra fue: " << letra;

}
```

Sin embargo el código no compila y me arroja como error:

> referencia a "stdscr" sin definir
>
> referencia a "wgetch" sin definir

Intenté también agregar al compilador "ncurses" [cómo pude leer aquí](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=10155.0) pero a pesar de hacerlo sigo sin poder mostrar el carácter en pantalla (Aunque esta vez compila):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué otra documentación podría leer para ver si puedo compilar los proyectos que impliquen manipulación de caracteres?

He leído este artículo: "How to include or link ncurses/curses library in Codeblocks 13.12 in Ubuntu 16.04" pero no encuentro el directorio boost (no copio el link porque no tengo reputación de más de 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has configurado **CodeBlocks** correctamente al seguir las instrucciones de ese artículo.

Lo que sucede es que **ncurses** necesita una inicialización previa al uso de sus funciones, y una limpieza final. La inicialización previa consiste en llamar a *initscr()*, mientras que antes del final del programa es necesario llamar a *endwin()*.

Por otra parte, **ncurses** incluye el concepto de *timeout*, es decir, hacer algo cuando ha pasado ya un cierto tiempo sin actividad (por ejemplo, esperar a que se pulse una tecla), así que es necesario desactivarlo con *timeout(-1)*. Con un parámetro negativo, la espera por la tecla es indefinida.

El código completo es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letra;

    initscr();
    timeout( -1 );

    cout << "ingrese letra" << endl;
    letra = getch();

    cout << "Su letra fue: " << letra;

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Espero que te ayude.